# Get the fonts used in a pdf using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, fonts, pdf.js

Is it possible to get the names of the fonts used in a pdf using pdf.js? I tried getting the metadata of a pdf document:

```
url="1.pdf";
PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function (pdfDoc_) {
        pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;   
        pdfDoc.getMetadata().then(function(stuff) {
            console.log(stuff); // Metadata object here
        }).catch(function(err) {
           console.log('Error getting meta data');
           console.log(err);
        });

       // Render the first page or whatever here
       // More code . . . 
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error getting PDF from ' + url);
        console.log(err);
    });
```

but the metadata does not seem to have font information. Can someone let me know how to find the fonts in a pdf using pdf.js?

Comment: You probably need to tap somewhere at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/core/evaluator.js#L631 and request content of all pages.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it. What do you mean?